# "Tags editing" or "Tags edit"?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

Can I say: "Tags edit" as a whole complete phrase, or should it be "Tags editing"?

Another thing, is it: "Did some tags editing" or "Did some tags edit"?

Thank you

---

I know "edit" is a noun, and "editing" is a gerund which takes the form of verb and functions as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be possible to use "tag" to modify "edit" as a noun, but generally an alternative phrasing would be better.

> John made three tag edits and one spelling-correction edit.

As an attributive, "tag" would usually be singular, even if "edits" is plural.

This kind of phrasing is possible, but it usually means you have to use a general purpose verb, like "make" or "do". It is better style to use the specific word "edit" as a verb:

> John edited three tags...

Answer (score 1):

"edit" can be a verb too. However, none of your phrases / sentences is proper in English.

You may say:

> Did you edit some tags?

or:

> Did you do some tag editing?

---

I cannot see how "tags edit" can be used as a phrase.

Without context, "tags editing" cannot be judged. Yes, it can be used.

---

You can use use "edit" as a noun like this:

> The tag **edit** had to be undone, because ...

or:

> The **editing** of the image is very laborious, because a very high quality is expected.

Comment: Not `Did you do edit some tags?`  but  `Did you edit some tags?`

Comment: Yeap, I almost replied the wrong explanation. I will correct it. Thank you. +1 The question marks inside the quoted text fooled me, and I understood it upside-down initially :)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't mean the question mark for the phrases but for the "is it" part. I wrote them in the colloquial way where you start the sentence with a verb.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @virolino's answer, consider:

`Did you do some editing of tags?`

or if it is singular:

`Did you edit a tag?`

Comment: Thank you. But I would also like to know when "edit" as a noun can be used correctly since @virolino mentioned that there is no such term as "tags edit".

Comment: Sorry, as a native speaker I wasn't taught anything about the language syntax!
Besides, English has more exceptions than rules, which makes it really hard to teach that way.